# Need the Keywords Search details form a Particular country

Tags: seo, visitor-pattern, visitor-statistic

I would like to know how to find the number of people searching for a particular keyword in particular country.

For example, I need the details of how many people are searching for "web hosting" in Oman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use keyword planner by google adword it may help you lot.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

check Google [adwords](http://www.google.co.in/AdWords) , there is lot of tools and it will help you